# Adding Floating Action Button to Recycler View Crash: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, crash, floating-action-button, material-components-android

I'm trying to add a unique floating action button to every item in a recycler grid view. I tried changing the theme to `MaterialComponent` but that didn't work. The error tells me the crash is occurring during inflation and that my theme is not `AppCompat` even though it is in styles. I think I might just have to add something into the XML but I am unsure. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.imagegridactivity, PID: 17829
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.imagegridactivity:layout/custom_view: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.imagegridactivity:layout/custom_view: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.imagegridactivity:layout/custom_view: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
        at com.example.imagegridactivity.AnimalsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AnimalsAdapter.java:135)
        at com.example.imagegridactivity.AnimalsAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AnimalsAdapter.java:29)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:561)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1204)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1204)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:723)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6872)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:25086)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3083)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1857)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2146)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7768)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:967)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:791)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:726)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:952)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:248)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:218)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:153)
        at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:81)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:212)
        at com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:201)
```

Adapter:

```
public class AnimalsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ImageView imageView;
    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    private Uri imageUri;
    private ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public ArrayList<animal_item> getDataSet() {
        return mDataSet;
    }

    public void setDataSet(ArrayList<animal_item> mDataSet) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public Uri getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(Uri imageUri) {
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {

        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {

        mListener = listener;

    }

    public AnimalsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet) {
        mDataSet = DataSet;
        mContext = context;
    }

    public ArrayList<animal_item> DataSet() {

        return mDataSet;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView mImageView;
        public FloatingActionButton mFloatingActionButton;
        public RelativeLayout mLinearLayout;

        public ViewHolder(View v, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(v);

            mImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            mFloatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);

            mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (listener != null) {

                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) ;
                        listener.onItemClick(position);
                    }
                }
            });
            mLinearLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.ll);
        }



        public ImageView getImageView() {

            return mImageView;
        }

        public void setImageView(ImageView mImageView) {

            this.mImageView = mImageView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AnimalsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.custom_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) mListener);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final animal_item animalItem = mDataSet.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(animalItem.getImageResource());

        imageView = holder.mImageView;

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="123dp"
    android:layout_height="123dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />


     <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@drawable/image_background_base"/>

    </RelativeLayout>



</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Styles:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.imagegridactivity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".PickImageActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.imagegridactivity"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0-rc01'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Context mContext;

    //RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private AnimalsAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private ArrayList<animal_item> arrayList;
    private Uri imageUri;

    private int imagePosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        //mRelativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.rl);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        final int[] imageArray = new int[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            imageArray[i] = R.drawable.image_background_base;

        }

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {

            int image = imageArray[i];
            arrayList.add(new animal_item(image));

        }

        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new AnimalsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);


                imagePosition = position;
            }
        });

        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN | ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, 0) {

            final ArrayList aL = new ArrayList<>();

            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {

                int position_dragged = dragged.getAdapterPosition();
                int position_target = target.getAdapterPosition();

                Collections.swap(arrayList, position_dragged, position_target);
                mAdapter.notifyItemMoved(position_dragged, position_target);
                //Collections.copy(mQuestion11List, aL);

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {

            }
        });

        helper.attachToRecyclerView(mRecyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        imageUri = data.getData();

        //mAdapter.getDataSet().get(imagePosition).setImageResource();

        mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition).findViewById(R.id.tv);

        Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(imageUri).centerCrop().into((ImageView) mLayoutManager.findViewByPosition(imagePosition).findViewById(R.id.tv));

    }
}
```

Main Activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#c2dbfd"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is mContext? What do you pass in this value?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That is the context of the MainActivity that is being passed into the adapter I think.

Comment: Can you post the code where you instantiate the adapter and pass the context?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Just added and the XML for the MainActivity and the Gradle

Comment: Just check the answer below. You need to pass the `Activity`, not an application `Context`. Just pay attention because the material components v1.1.0 requires a `Theme.MaterialComponents` theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
> The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.AppCompat (or a descendant).
> ```

There is an issue with the `context` used to instantiate the `Adapter`. You need to pass in the `Activity`, **not an `ApplicationContext`**.
The application context **doesn't have** your app theme.

In your Activity change

```
mContext = getApplicationContext();
mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(mContext, arrayList);
```

to

```
mAdapter = new AnimalsAdapter(this, arrayList);
```

Also pay attention since with the Material Components 1.1.0 your app theme should inherit from a [Material Components theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes).

Comment: Thank you! Going to do some research now on this!

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your app needs to have the theme. To do that, in your manifest file, in your application tag add your theme:

```
<application 
          your application configurations
          android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

And in your app build.gradle add the following dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Let me know if it works :)

Comment: just completed the answer, let me know if it does the trick to you

Comment: Same error, unfortunately. I didn't have the core:core implementation in before though. Added now.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the material design package in your app's build.gradle file?

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    // ...
}
```

Read more here
https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/

Comment: I did. 'implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' Added the build.gradle to the post